# How to properly install and configure PyCharm IDE in NixOS?

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter, nix, nixos

In NixOS, I have chosen to install `pycharm-community` via the NixOS configuration adding these lines to `configuration.nix`:

```
  environment.systemPackages = [
    pkgs.jetbrains.pycharm-community
  ];
```

Now when I run PyCharm and try to create a new project for the first time, it will prompt to add a **Python interpreter**. However by default, the dropdown list for the interpreter is empty and I do not know how to locate my python interpreter.

Saw some posts about writing a `shell.nix` file that has a certain `postShellHook` configuration. (https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/i16zvd/how_to_make_pycharm_use_nixshell/)

Though I don't know how can I write that and where it should be located. I still have very little knowledge on NixOS and will appreciate a simple step-by-step solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not use PyCharm but from I understood from the Reddit posts, you need to use one of the proposed `shell.nix` to generated a `virtualenv` in the project folder. Then you activate the shell using `nix-shell` and you start PyCharm from the command line inside this shell.

Comment: Point the `PYCHARM_PYTHON_PATH` env var to the `python` binary provided by nix before launching PyCharm.
e.g.
`PYCHARM_PYTHON_PATH=$(which python)  pycharm-community`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an interpreter by giving Pycharm the right path.

You need to have python installed then just run the which command and give the result to Pycharm when asked for the location of a local interpreter

```
>> which python3
/run/current-system/sw/bin/python3
```

Answer (score -1):

The "new" way to use nix would be flakes.

a very simple flake file such as the following will allow you to `nix develop` into a shell that has python3 in it by default.

```
{
  inputs = {
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOs/nixpkgs/release-23.05";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils}:
  let supported-systems = [ "x86_64-linux" "aarch64-linux" "x86_64-darwin" ]; in
  flake-utils.lib.eachSystem supported-systems
  (system:
    let
      pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
    in {
        devShell = pkgs.mkShell { buildInputs=[pkgs.jetbrains.pycharm-community pkgs.python3]; };
    }
  );
}
```

After running `nix develop`, a `pycharm-community` will have the proper access to python3 to run its code.

Comment: this site has a bunch of useful information: https://serokell.io/blog/practical-nix-flakes

Comment: Have tried to setup the same flake, after `nix-develop` and running `pycharm-community` inside it, still it finds no python interpreter. Can you verify this?

Comment: @simpleboy0 I cannot verify this. This is explicitly what this flake is suppose to do. Do you get any errors after `nix develop`?  If you do a `where python3` right after `nix develop` what is the output?